# Carousel Seating Logic Puzzle

Tags: logical-deduction, visual, logic-grid

Puzzle from my good friend and fellow Sporcle user, [AuroraIllumina](https://www.sporcle.com/user/AuroraIllumina/quizzes/)!

Eight children are riding the carousel: four girls (Anna, Beth, Claire, Diana), and four boys (Eric, Frank, George, Henry). It is your job to determine which position each of them is sitting in.

Rules:

> - The two people with 6-letter names are opposite each other (four seats apart)
> - None of the people with 5-letter names are adjacent to one another
> - Each boy is adjacent to exactly one girl
> - Exactly two people are in seats with the same number of letters in their name, both are boys
> - Frank is not adjacent to George
> - Beth and Claire are both the same distance from Anna (based on the number of seats)
> - If the carousel rotated 180 degrees, then three girls would end up in positions with the same number of letters as their names

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 and 1

> Claire Diana

3 and 8

> Frank Beth

4 and 7

> Eric Henry

5 and 6

> Anna George

with the picture

> [image]

Comment: You seem to have used Claire twice and omitted Anna.

Comment: yep little mistake while rewritting

Comment: You got it, good job!

Answer (score 5):

Solution:

> 1 Diana
>  2 Claire
>  3 Frank
>  4 Eric
>  5 Anna
>  6 George
>  7 Henry
>  8 Beth

Why?

> If the carousel rotated 180 degrees, then three girls would end up in positions with the same number of letters as their names.
>  > Claire has to be opposite of 6 > Claire=2
>  > Diana has to be opposite of 5 > Diana=1
>  > another girl has to be opposite of 4 > Anna/Beth=8
>
>  The two people with 6-letter names are opposite each other (four seats apart)
>  > since Claire is on 2, George has to be on 6
>
>  Each boy is adjacent to exactly one girl
>  > a girl has to be on 5 > Anna/Beth=5
>
>  Exactly two people are in seats with the same number of letters in their name, both are boys
>  > Eric has to be on 4
>
>  Frank is not adjacent to George
>  > only 3 is left for Frank
>  > only 7 is left for Henry
>
>  Beth and Claire are both the same distance from Anna (based on the number of seats)
>  > Beth=8
>  > Anna=5

Answer (score 2):

> 1. Diana (clue 7)
>  2. Claire (clue 7)
>  3. Frank (clue 5)
>  4. Eric (clue 3&4)
>  5. Anna (clue 6)
>  6. George (clue 3&4)
>  7. Henry (clue 5)
>  8. Beth (clue 6)